# Why does Serial.print print out the wrong thing?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I am using a flame sensor. I am reading the state and then printing it. Here is my code:

```
void loop(){
 flameState = digitalRead(flamePin);//variables already defined and are global
existsFire();//calls the void
delay(1000);
}

void existsFire(){

Serial.println("Flame: " + flameState);

}
```

Before, this printed out the right thing. Today, it was printing out "lame:". The "F" and the flameState were missing. I changed it to:

```
void existsFire(){

Serial.print("Flame: ");
Serial.println(flameState);

}
```

Everything worked fine. Is there a problem with my Arduino Mega. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've stumbled across the difference in the C++ language between a `String` and an "array of characters". What you gave `Serial.println()` was an array of characters:

```
Serial.println("Flame: "...);
```

and then tried to add a number to it.

```
Serial.println("Flame: " + flameState);
```

If it had have been a `String`, then what you typed would have been fine:

```
String flame = "Flame: ";
Serial.println(flame + flameState);
```

Adding (literally `+`) a number to a `String` adds characters to the `String` to represent the number. Unfortunately you didn't start with a `String`, you started with an array of characters:

```
"Flame: "
```

Adding a number to THAT changes where the array starts. `flameState` must have been `1`, and `"Flame: " + 1` would have been `"lame :"` - as you found out!

The version that worked did so through a little bit of magic:

```
Serial.print("Flame: ");
Serial.println(flameState);
```

The first line called a version of `print()` that accepted an array of characters and printed each of them out. The second line called a *different* version of `println()` that accepted a number and printed out its representation as a series of characters (digits) - followed by a new line (the `ln` part of the name).